# RecyclerView EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener in activity

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеется `RecyclerViewCursorAdapter` в котором расположен `EditText`. В него заносится количество товара для заказа.

Нужно сохранять данные из поля для ввода после изменения (в данном случае после потери фокуса. Про `TextChangedListener` тоже думал, но пока остановился на этом варианте), записывать изменения в БД (чтобы случайно не потерять данные) и дублировать в `SparseIntArray` (хранит количество для динамического вывода), и делать пересчет суммы на странице в отдельный элемент активити.

Попробовал добавлять `holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener` в `onBindViewHolder` , данные recyclerview обновляются нормально, но не понятно как работать с view содержимым активити, чтобы пересчитать и вывести сумму и количество в товара в корзине?

p.s. программирование больше хобби, чем профессия. Буду благодарен за любую идею.

Comment: а куда вы пишите все, что в корзину отложили? в БД? тогда при добавлении в корзину сразу заносите в БД инфу о товаре, в активити просто делаете выборку и получаете оттуда всю нужную инфу.

Comment: да дублирую информацию в бд, чтобы не потерять информацию. Но застрял как раз на взаимодействии адаптера с другими элементами активити

Comment: вам не нужно получать эту информацию из адаптера. Получайте ее прямо из БД

Comment: я получаю данные из бд и расчитываю при запуске все нужные элементы. а проблема в том, что я пока еще не разбираюсь как из адаптера в активити передать команду пересчета нужных элементов.

Comment: это как раз правильнее всего сделать через интерфейс, как написано в ответе, только передавать не данные, которые вводили, а просто реагировать на событие (как, например, реакция на событие клика кнопки). То есть, в адаптере при изменениях в полях ввода вызываете интерфейс. В подписанной на этот интерфейс активити, в реализации метода интерфейса, делаете выборку нужных данных из БД, рассчитываете и выводите на виджет.

Comment: именно так я и сделал уже, все получилось. спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи данных из RecyclerView в Activity я бы делал через интерфейс:

1) Создайте интерфейс

```
public interface RecyclerViewEditTextChanged {
    void onPriceChanged(int price);
}
```

2) В активити перед инициализацией адаптера реализуйте интерфейс:

```
RecyclerViewEditTextChanged recyclerEditTextChanged = new RecyclerViewEditTextChanged(){
        @Override
        public void onPriceChanged(int price){          
                priceTextView.setText(price); //отображаете цену в активити...
        }
}
```

3) в recycler adapter кроме контекста, передайте интерфейс из пункта 2)

```
adapter = new RecyclerViewCursorAdapter (getContext(), recyclerEditTextChanged);
```

4) имплементируйте коллбек в адаптере

```
private final RecyclerViewEditTextChanged recyclerEditTextChanged;
public RecyclerViewCursorAdapter (Context context, RecyclerViewEditTextChanged listener){
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerEditTextChanged = listener;
}
```

5) передайте данные через интерфейс в активити

```
  holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            recyclerEditTextChanged.onPriceChanged(Integer.parseInt(holder.editText.getText().toString));
        }
    });
```

Comment: спасибо, мысль понял, буду пробовать

Comment: На вашем примере, реализовал нужный мне код. Все работает как нужно. Еще раз спасибо!